# How to have seperate URI properties using api-blueprint and Aglio?

Tags: apiblueprint

I am following the examples in the docs, in order to understand the syntax and how it works.

So I create this md file

```
# Blog Posts [/posts{?limit}]
 ...    

## Retrieve Blog Posts [GET]
Retrieves the list of **ACME Blog** posts.

+ Parameters
    + limit (optional, number) ... Maximum number of posts ot retrieve

+ Response 200

        ...

### Create a Post [POST]
+ Request

        ...

+ Response 201

        ...
```

and after I run aglio I get a nice looking html but with one problem. the "{?limit}" appers to the POST url as well. This is really bad, looking for many hours and can't understand how to bypass this.

Comment: At apiary works good, display logic have to be added into aglio generator, try add issue to https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues

Comment: Just copied the sample code to apiary and again, doesn't work. You can see that here http://docs.test2278.apiary.io/

Comment: Sorry, You have to use new documentation: [http://docs.test2278.apiary.io/?3ColumnDocumentation=1](http://docs.test2278.apiary.io/?3ColumnDocumentation=1)